# Adding package name to copyright profile in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, copyright-display

I'm using Intellij idea. I need to add copyright for package name across the project

tried with ${PACKAGE_NAME} and $pacakage.name but no luck. Also, tried with

```
 $file.qualifiedClassName
```

but it gets the package along with class name.  Let me know the possible variable for getting the package name in copyright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copyright profiles are using [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/) engine under the hood. You can try something like:

```
#set( $dot = "." )
#set( $final=$dot + $file.className)
$file.qualifiedClassName.replace($final, "")
```